# Accordion list with OnsenUI

Tags: onsen-ui

Is this possible with OnsenUI?  http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz

I am sure I saw a demo of it in the docs before the 1.1 update, but I can't find it now. Does such a demo exist and, more importantly, is it possible to do this with the framework?

The trivial example below is not encouraging:

```
<ons-list>           
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">One</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">
        <ons-list>           
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">One</ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron">Two</ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Please see http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/vjlsF

Note that different from ionic, Onsen UI does not include ngAnimate initially. You should use the
following statement.

```
angular.module('myApp',['onsen','ngAnimate'])
```

Comment: Thank you KNaito. It wasn't a very intelligent question after all, seems so obvious now.  This might be further ignorance on my part; the only difference I see now is that in the ionic example, there is a slight delay on the grey title colour when a group collapses (and possibly when the group opens). It just makes it all look a bit smoother. Is this something that I can change?  It's a minor point, but something I thought I'd ask.  Thank you again.